# Iptables: how to block all incoming connections from outside the lan

Tags: iptables

I have a small server (connected to Internet through a VDSL router), with some services that have to work only for the LAN.

I don't trust very much the router, so I have to protect the server and client via iptables/windows firewall.

On the server I have set iptables for allowing only connection for my services, but I would to reject ALL the incoming connections from Internet, and allow LAN connections.

I have tried to add this line to iptables:
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -t filter ! -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j REJECT
but it blocks even the ping, the http, the ftp connection on internet.
If I remove that line, all the connections are ok.

Someone can tell me the correct syntax?

Comment: You have to remember that firewall look at **packets** by default.  If you want the firewall to be able to make connections to services outside your network, it needs to accept the replies.  You need stateful rules.  So it isn't the syntax of a specific rule that is wrong, it is your understanding of how the firewall needs to function.  There are hundreds of iptables guides on the internet, I think you would be better served by reading a few of them.

Comment: BTW, you should also consider just using a iptables front end like firehol or something.  It might make it easier for you to write a policy that you want .

Comment: Side note: newer kernels use nftables instead of iptables. You should start to switch to it.